# Deleting user directly from cloud at Parse framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I am using the following code at my `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` function,

```
[PFUser enableAutomaticUser];
[[PFUser currentUser] saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if (succeeded && !error) {
        [[UserContainer sharedUserContainer] addUser:[PFUser currentUser]];
    }
}];
```

hoping that if the user was removed from the database, this would create a new user, or resurrect the previous user. This completes with no error and with succeeded = true, but there is no data at the cloud.

Is this expected or a bug? How should I handle recreating new anonymous users when the existing user is deleted?

Comment: Could you clarify a bit? You want this piece of code to check for a current user, and if they don't exist in the DB, you want to create an automatic user, correct?

Comment: @RyanKreager Yes, exactly.

Comment: Your automatic user might not be saving due to having nothing to save. Have you tried adding a property to the automatic user before saving?